# What do the statement mean by "leaves every element of $F$ fixed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> If $p(x) \in F[x]$ and $a,b$ are both roots of an irreducible polynomial $p(x),$ then $F(a) \cong F(b)$ by an isomorphism which takes $a$ onto $b$ and leaves every element of $F$ fixed.

Simple question: What precisely does this statement mean by "leaves every element of $F$ fixed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if $\varphi$ is the name for the isomorphism then $\varphi(c)=c$ for all $c\in F$.

Comment: Thank you, what I was thinking but I wasn't so sure